# Pigtailed switch from outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle

I'm in the process of wiring an outlet and a switch to control a light fixture. I wanted to check if my wiring is correct before proceeding further.

Here's the setup:

- I have a 14/2 wire entering a 2-gang box.
- From this wire, I plan to connect it to an outlet to provide power.
- Additionally, I'll have a switch in the same box to control a light fixture.
- The hot wire from the 14/2 will provide power to the outlet.
- A pigtail will go from the outlet to the switch.
- Ground & Neutral wires from the 14/2 wire and the light fixture will be bonded together and connected to the outlet. White to white and then bare to bare.
- Light fixture is a new 4' shop light, mounted to the ceiling and is hardwired. It did not come with a plug.

I have limited experience when it comes to electrical and wanted to confirm before I proceed. It seems right to me but I may be missing something.

Comment: Are you running all new cables for this?  Or are the cables already there, and is there a cable from the light's junction box to this junction box already?

Comment: 14/3 is usually black, red, white plus ground.  If you only have black, white plus ground it is 14/2.  Ground and neutral is only bonded together at the main panel.

Comment: New cabling. 14/3 comes into the box and another run of 14/3 goes to the light fixture.

Comment: Ahh, it is 14/2. Sorry about that.

Comment: Not sure if bonded was the correct term. I connected them with a wire nut that has a hole in the end to allow a pigtail of sorts to connect to the outlet.

Comment: If you mean that the neutral (white) wires are connected together and the ground (bare) wires are connected together and are NOT connected to each other , but connected via a pigtail to the proper screws on the outlet...then you are correct.

Comment: Just keep ground and neutral separated from each other, so white to white and bare to bare.  Bonded means connecting to each other.

Comment: @RMDman Yes, white to white and then connected to the terminal screw on the outlet. Same for the ground.

Comment: @ Matt, neutral, as you probably know, on the silver screw...then you are good to go.

Comment: If one of you wants to type up an answer I'll gladly accept. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Is the receptacle going to be in the same 2-gang box as the switch? Or is the receptacle going to be located at some distance away? What height above the floor will this 2-gang box be located? Will it be close by an entrance doorway? There is supposed to be a light switch at shoulder height by a doorway so the light can be turned on before or as one enters a room. But usually a receptacle in living space is lower on the wall and not right by a doorway. What is going to be the use for this receptacle? Moving the receptacle down to 14" above the floor would be easy, moving laterally harder

Comment: Locating a receptacle in a bedroom in the middle of a wall often puts it behind a dresser or chest. Maybe it would be better to locate a bedroom receptacle right by a doorway. It would certainly work better for a vacuum.

Comment: The box is near a work bench in the garage and the receptacle is right next to the switch, in the same 2 gang box. @JimStewart

Comment: OK so note that most receptacles in a garage are supposed to have GFCI protection. This can be from a GFCI breaker or GFCI receptacle. Is the incoming power (hot/neutral pair) going to be on a new circuit that you will install or are you extending an existing circuit?

Comment: @JimStewart Understood. I ran a new wire to the light as it got moved to a better location and am reusing the line coming into the box, added the outlet so I had power next to the work bench.

Comment: What kind of light are you thinking about? If this is a workbench light to be mounted on the wall at medium height above the workbench, then think about whether this should be a hardwired fixture or a plug-in. If you would add these details to your question, experienced experts here might offer advice on this choice. I wonder if there are LED fixtures that could be raised or lowered for best illumination? I am 79 yo and so I always need good light.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151144/discussion-between-matt-and-jim-stewart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cabling required is different depending on whether the line hot and its neutral (from the breaker) enter the circuit in the ceiling box or in the switch box.

If the line hot enters in the ceiling box, you would need a 3-conductor cable (black, red, and white) between the light fixture box in the ceiling and the switch box. The receptacle must have a line hot and a neutral. The ceiling box must have a switched hot and a neutral.

If the line hot and its neutral enters in the switch box, then you can wire it all with 2-conductor cable (black and white).

Comment: Line hot enters the switch box.  My concern was mainly the pigtail from the always hot outlet feeding the switch but after discussing with everyone it seems that is a non issue.

Comment: How about reporting on the light fixture you are installing.

Comment: It is a 4' LED shop light, no plug, hardwire only which I am totally fine with.